# Openssl SSL_CTX_new is successfull but set errno to ENOSYS (Function not implemented)

Tags: networking, macos, openssl, c, tls

The SSL_CTX_new() function works fine but something is strange it sets errno to ENOSYS.

Documentation doesn't say anything about this :
https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_CTX_new.html

```
#include <errno.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]){

    SSL_library_init();
    SSL_load_error_strings();

    perror("A");

    SSL_CTX * sslContext = SSL_CTX_new(TLS_server_method());

    if (sslContext == NULL){
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    perror("B");

    return 0;
}
```

this code returns this :

```
A: Undefined error: 0
B: Function not implemented
```

My openssl version is : OpenSSL 1.1.1b  26 Feb 2019

Comment: Welcome to Super User! What problem are you trying to solve? This seems quite programming-related.

Comment: thanks :) I'm trying to understand why SSL_CTX_new sets errno. It might means there is an error somewhere

Comment: If this is about a program you yourself are writing and compiling, and your question is about an API giving you an error, it might be better off one of our sister sites such as [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com)

Comment: yes it is a program i wrote, i will move to stack overflow, thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not all libraries use errno to report status. If the documentation does not explicitly say that this function sets errno, then the value is best thought of as **undefined**: the function might preserve the original value, or set it to 0, or leave some garbage in it.

And indeed the OpenSSL documentation does not say anything about errno; instead the library has its own "error stack" that you can access using [ERR_get_error()](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/ERR_get_error.html), and this provides more precise error codes and messages than the very limited set provided by libc.

So the value you find in errno is just a leftover from some or other libc function that SSL_CTX_new() used *internally*. (For example, it might have tried to seed the RNG by calling libc getrandom(), which then returned ENOSYS due to lack of kernel support.)